# Async is not working in Cloud Function + TypeScript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on counting subscribers numbers in users/campaigns on Firebase Cloud Function. But the error occurs when the result total numbers runs faster than running total numbers.

```
export const howManySubscribers = async () => {
  await firestoreRef
    .collection('users')
    .get()
    .then((userQuerySnapshot) => {
      userQuerySnapshot.forEach((userDoc) => {
        if (!userDoc) return
        userDoc.ref
          .collection('campaigns')
          .get()
          .then(async (campaignQuerySnapshot) => {
            await campaignQuerySnapshot.forEach(async (campaignDoc) => {

              const subscribersNumber = await campaignDoc.ref
                .collection('subscribers')
                .get()
                .then(async (subscriberQuerySnapshot) => {

                  return await subscriberQuerySnapshot.size
                })

              totalSubscribersNumber =
                totalSubscribersNumber + subscribersNumber
            // running total numbers
              console.log('running total numbers', totalNewSubscribersNumber)
              })
            // result total numbers
            console.log('result total numbers', totalNewSubscribersNumber)
          })
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the error occurs"?  Please edit the question to include more information about the error and how that's different than what you expect.

Comment: Also, you should note that forEach doesn't return a promise, so it doesn't make sense to `await` it.  async/await doesn't work in a forEach lambda function the way you're expecting it to.

Comment: You should read up on how to use `async await` and what problem it is trying to solve. You are mixing these with `.then` calls a lot, which makes your code pretty hard to understand. I strongly suggest either fully sticking to `async await` or not using it at all.

Answer (score 1):

The main Problem is that you are not `awaiting` the promise chains correctly. At some points, you await something that does not return a promise (e.g. `forEach`). I strongly suggest refactoring your code to take full advantage of `async await` and not mix it with `then` too much, as it makes your code easier to understand and see where you need to await something. In your case, it could look something like this:

```
export const howManySubscribers = async () => {
  // Get the users (note: await does return the unwrapped value from the return Promise)
  const userQuerySnapshot = await firestoreRef.collection('users').get(); 

  // Get all campaigns, use Promise.all to wait for everything to finish. This will return an Array of the resolved campaigns. Also, leverage 'filter' and 'map'.
  const campaignQuerySnapshots = await Promise.all(
    userQuerySnapshot
      .filter(userDoc => !!userDoc)
      .map(userDoc => userDoc.ref.collection('campaigns').get())
  );

  // Again, use Promise.all to wait for all subscribers to return a value and unwrap it with await
  const subscriberQuerySnapshots = await Promise.all(
    campaignQuerySnapshots.map(campaignDoc => campaignDoc.ref.collection('subscribers').get())
  );
  
  // Now you can just add all sizes from your subscribers and have your total
  const totalNewSubscribersNumber = subscriberQuerySnapshots.map(snap => snap.size).reduce((acc, size) => acc + size, 0);


  // result total numbers
  console.log('result total numbers', totalNewSubscribersNumber)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` doesn't work with `await` at all. What you can use is

```
for (item of campaignQuerySnapshot) {
  //do something here with item
}
```

This works with `async` and `await`. You can read more about it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) question